# Show 3 buttons on selecting any value from drop down list

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to display 3 buttons on selecting any value from drop down list. I wrote following code but it is not working.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
        $("#myList").change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "") {
                $("#outer").hide();
            } else {
                $("#outer").show();
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<select id="myList">
    <option value="1">device 1</option>
    <option value="2">device 2</option>
    <option value="3">device 3</option>
</select>

<div id="outer" style="display: none">
    <div class="inner"><button type="submit" class="Btn1" 
    onClick="return false;" >button 1</button></div>
   <div class="inner"><button type="submit" class="Btn2" onClick="return 
    false;">button 2</button></div>
   <div class="inner"><button class="submit" class="Btn3" 
    onClick="return false">button 3</button></div>
</div>
```

But this is not working on selecting any value from drop down list.What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its working fine for me with your exact code...
i added this to see that every time you select `<option value="">--Make a choice--</option>` your code gets fired.
Maybe you forgot to add jquery to your site?

```js
   $(function () {
        $("#myList").change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "") {
                $("#outer").hide();
            } else {
                $("#outer").show();
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="myList">
    <option value="">--Make a choice--</option>
    <option value="1">device 1</option>
    <option value="2">device 2</option>
    <option value="3">device 3</option>
</select>

<div id="outer" style="display: none">
    <div class="inner"><button type="submit" class="Btn1" 
    onClick="return false;" >button 1</button></div>
   <div class="inner"><button type="submit" class="Btn2" onClick="return 
    false;">button 2</button></div>
   <div class="inner"><button class="submit" class="Btn3" 
    onClick="return false">button 3</button></div>
</div>
```